# Installing Ethereum - missing backup.json file

Tags: go-ethereum

I've donwloaded .../win64-0-8-10.zip.
Unpacked with 7ZIP.
Created Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-8-10 folder.
Executed Ethereum Wallet.exe

When I click Use The Main Network it ask for .../_backup.json file.
Folder .../Appdata/Roaming/Ethereum/keystore is empty.
Nothing received by email.

How to continue ?